# how do I redirect the contents of one file to others?

Tags: awk, while-loop

I have this file test.in

```
    $cat test.in
    Topic: Topic1   Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1  Offline: 
    Topic: Topic1   Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1  Offline: 
    Topic: Topic1   Partition: 2    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2 Isr: 2  Offline: 
    Topic: Topic1   Partition: 3    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3 Isr: 3  Offline: 
    Topic: Topic1   Partition: 4    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3 Isr: 3  Offline: 
    Topic: Topic1   Partition: 5    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2 Isr: 2  Offline:
```

I want to divide this file as many times as there are leaders.
The file has among its parameters the definition of Topic, Partition, Leader,etc. For our example there are 3 leaders (they can be more)

With Topic and Partition values I want to build a new content.

For that I use:

```
while read line
> do
> awk '{print "bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic="$2",partition="$4}' 
> done <test
```

And I get:

```
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=1
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=2
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=3
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=4
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=5
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=6
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=7
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=8
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=9
```

But I want divide the out to diferente file depend of the leader definition on test.in.

I want my output like:

```
$cat Broker1
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=0
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=1

$cat Broker2
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=2
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=5

$cat Broker3
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=3
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=4
```

I try to do it modifying the while-loop in this way:

```
while read line
> do
> BROKER=$(awk '{print $6}')
> awk '{print "bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic="$2",partition="$4}' >>broker."$BROKER"
> done <test.in
```

But I got this error:

```
-bash: broker.$BROKER: ambiguous redirect
```

And I don't understand what is wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for showing your efforts in form of code, IMHO could you please be more clear in your samples of input and expected output as it is not clear how you want to generate output files? What is the relation of your shown sample of Input_file and your shown output file, kindly do edit your question with more details and let us know then.

Comment: RavinderSingh13, I hope I have improved the explanation

Comment: Just redirect within awk based on the field.  eg `awk '{print > ("leader" $6)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The robust, portable, efficient way to do this is to sort the input by leader first so you can close output files being created as the leader value changes:

```
$ cat -n file |
sort -k7,7 -k1,1n |
awk '
    $7 != prev { close(out); out="Broker"$7; prev=$7 }
    { print "bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic="$3",partition="$5 > out }
'
```

.

```
$ head -20 Broker*
==> Broker1 <==
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=0
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=1

==> Broker2 <==
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=2
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=5

==> Broker3 <==
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=3
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=4
```

The `cat` is to add line numbers so that after `sort` the relative order of the lines for each leader value is the same as it was before. If you use GNU sort then `-s` (for "stable sort") does the same.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one,it works without using any other external commands (another way):

```
awk '
{ 
    array[$6]=array[$6]";"$0
    
}
END{
    for(i in array){
        num++
    }

    for(x=1; x <= num ; x++){           
        num_a=split(array[x], array_a, ";")
    
        for(y=2; y <= num_a; y++){
            split(array_a[y],array_b)
            output="Broker"array_b[6]
            
            print "bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic="array_b[2]",partition="array_b[4] > output
        }
        close(output)
    }
}' input_file
```

This awk script is compatible with GNU and POSIX.

Result:

```
head Broker*
==> Broker1 <==
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=0
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=1

==> Broker2 <==
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=2
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=5

==> Broker3 <==
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=3
bean kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=Topic1,partition=4
```

Comment: I changed the script to make it compatible with the different version of AWK.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I made some adjustments.